# How do I parse info from a command and output it?

Tags: parsing, batch-file, cmd, system-information

I haven't written a batch file for a few years, and I've forgotten how to do this.
My code displays the OS Name.

Code:

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name"
```

It then says

> OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 8.1

(there is a huge space in between)

I want it to display the OS Name without actually outputting "OS Name:" and have the huge space. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in ('systeminfo ^| findstr /B /C:"OS Name" ') do echo "%%c"
```